# How to recode multiple-conditionals to -1/0/+1?

Tags: r, recode

I have my data like:

```
Name A B C
apple 1 -1 0
banana 2 -2 1
pear -3 0 1
```

I want to replace all positive value to -1, all negative values to +1, but remain the 0 to be 0, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use `sign` to get the sign of all the elements of the dataframe and then reverse it by multiplying it to -1.

```
df[-1] <- sign(df[-1]) * -1

df
#    Name  A B  C
#1  apple -1 1  0
#2 banana -1 1 -1
#3   pear  1 0 -1
```

From `?sign`

> sign returns a vector with the signs of the corresponding elements of x (the sign of a real number is 1, 0, or -1 if the number is positive, zero, or negative, respectively).

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("apple", "banana", 
"pear"), class = "factor"), A = c(-1, -1, 1), B = c(1, 1, 0), 
C = c(0, -1, -1)), .Names = c("Name", "A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: why not simplify to `-sign(df[-1])`?

Comment: @AndreElrico yes, that would give the same result as well.

Answer (score 1):

By no means this is as good as the top voted, but here is an alternative:

```
ans <- df1[,-1] / -abs(df1[,-1])
ans[sapply(ans,is.nan)] <- 0

#> ans
#   A B  C
#1 -1 1  0
#2 -1 1 -1
#3  1 0 -1
```